# Can F1 students work simultaneously on-campus and off-campus with a total of 22 hours during academic year?

Tags: united-states, visa

I am an international Ph.D. student with F1 status. I'm wondering is it possible to simultaneously work as Research Assistant (20 hours/week, on-campus) and also work on part-time CPT (2 hours/week, off-campus), i.e., in total, 22 hours per week, during the academic year (Fall, Winter, and Spring terms)? I will take courses for the part-time CPT work.

I have asked this question from the international office of our university and they answered there is no problem with this. I have also found [this website](https://iss.wisc.edu/employment/f1-employment/f-1-curricular-practical-training-cpt/cpt-on-campus-employment/) which indicates it is possible.

Comment: Is this CPT thing a paid or unpaid internship?

Comment: It is a paid internship.